# React Native Maps issue with overlaying components

Tags: react-native-maps

I am trying to overlay some elements in the middle and too of a map but to no avail. So far i've attempted to use 'OverlayComponent' as described on the documentation

```
render() {
  return (
    <MapView
      region={this.state.region}
    />
    <OverlayComponent
      style={{position: “absolute”, bottom: 50}}
    />
  );
}
```

This component it seems isn't really exported by `react-native-maps` anymore as

`import MapView, { OverlayComponent } from 'react-native-maps';`

yields undefined for `OverlayComponent`.

Any ideas? I am a bit at a loss as to how i should approach this.

I tried overlaying a `View` over the map with `pointerEvents` set to `none` which works but one of the elements im trying to overlay needs to capture input, specifically its a TextInput im trying to turn into a searchbar.

Thanks a bungh

Comment: I believe `OverlayComponent` is just an example of a component but not an actual thing exported.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`react-native-maps` has an `<Overlay>` [Component API](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/overlay.md). That seems to be suitable for images only.

Why not overlay something like `TouchableOpacity` by positioning it absolutely and wrapping the whole thing in a `<View>`:

```
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

...

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        ...
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.overlay}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Touchable Opacity</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
  overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. this is what i ended up doing in the end, there were a few bugs with it like the view capturing all events but all got solved in the end. 

Wish it was clearer in the documentation. OverlayComponent still yields undefined for example

Comment: @Return-1 how did you prevented the view from capturing all the events?

Answer (score 4):

We took the mapbox pill and life was better in oh so many ways for the entire team : )

Comment: Good choice! The React and React Native Google Map implementations has been made by aliens and not for human mindset.